# Blur the whole screen with SDL and C

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2, game-development

I've come upon these 2 posts:

> [How to blur SDL_Surface without shaders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521891/how-to-blur-sdl-surface-without-shaders#29556405)

> https://bacprogramming.wordpress.com/2018/01/10/box-blur-with-sdl2/

Both cover how to blur an *SDL_Surface* without the need of shaders like this:

```
void blur() //This manipulates with SDL_Surface and gives it box blur effect
{
    for (int y = 0; y < imageSurface->h; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < (imageSurface->pitch / 4); x++)
        {
            Uint32 color = ((Uint32*)imageSurface->pixels)[(y * (imageSurface->pitch / 4)) + x];
 
            //SDL_GetRGBA() is a method for getting color
            //components from a 32 bit color
            Uint8 r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0;
            SDL_GetRGBA(color, imageSurface->format, &r, &g, &b, &a);
 
            Uint32 rb = 0, gb = 0, bb = 0, ab = 0;
 
            //Within the two for-loops below, colors of adjacent pixels are added up
 
            for (int yo = -blur_extent; yo <= blur_extent; yo++)
            {
                for (int xo = -blur_extent; xo <= blur_extent; xo++)                 {                   if (y + yo >= 0 && x + xo >= 0
                        && y + yo < imageSurface->h && x + xo < (imageSurface->pitch / 4)
                        )
                    {
                        Uint32 colOth = ((Uint32*)imageSurface->pixels)[((y + yo)
                                                * (imageSurface->pitch / 4)) + (x + xo)];
 
                        Uint8 ro = 0, go = 0, bo = 0, ao = 0;
                        SDL_GetRGBA(colOth, imageSurface->format, &ro, &go, &bo, &ao);
 
                        rb += ro;
                        gb += go;
                        bb += bo;
                        ab += ao;
                    }
                }
            }
 
            //The sum is then, divided by the total number of
            //pixels present in a block of blur radius
 
            //For blur_extent 1, it will be 9
            //For blur_extent 2, it will be 25
            //and so on...
 
            //In this way, we are getting the average of
            //all the pixels in a block of blur radius
 
            //(((blur_extent * 2) + 1) * ((blur_extent * 2) + 1)) calculates
            //the total number of pixels present in a block of blur radius
 
            r = (Uint8)(rb / (((blur_extent * 2) + 1) * ((blur_extent * 2) + 1)));
            g = (Uint8)(gb / (((blur_extent * 2) + 1) * ((blur_extent * 2) + 1)));
            b = (Uint8)(bb / (((blur_extent * 2) + 1) * ((blur_extent * 2) + 1)));
            a = (Uint8)(ab / (((blur_extent * 2) + 1) * ((blur_extent * 2) + 1)));
 
            //Bit shifting color bits to form a 32 bit proper colour
            color = (r) | (g << 8) | (b << 16) | (a << 24);
            ((Uint32*)imageSurface->pixels)[(y * (imageSurface->pitch / 4)) + x] = color;
        }
    }
}
```

**Is it possible to blur the whole screen instead of a surface** (**or somehow convert everything that's seen in the screen into a surface that can then be blurred**)?

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627015/sdl-image-add-blur-filter-to-code-in-c) may help.

Comment: Example of [box blur](https://bacprogramming.wordpress.com/2018/01/10/box-blur-with-sdl2/) with code examples